# release of object causing error

Tags: ios, layer

So i'm working on an application, and i'm not using automatic reference counting, so i have to do my own memory management. I have this code, which sets a value to a UIView's layer in a first method.
Then in a second method, i retrieve it. array1 is defined in my `viewDidLoad`

Here is my first Method

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGFloat endLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(startLocation.x, startLocation.y, endLocation.x, endLocation.y);
    UIView *rectstring = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pencilbool];
    [[rectstring layer] setValue:string forKey:@"color"];
    NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",stepper.value];
    [[rectstring layer] setValue:string1 forKey:@"size234"];

        [array1 addObject:rectstring];
        [rectstring release];
        [string release];
        [string1 release];

}
```

Second method:

```
 -(IBAction)secondmethod {
        for (UIView *string1 in array1) {
            CGContextRef gc=UIGraphicGetCurrentContext();
            CGFloat width =[[string1.layer valueForKey:@"size234"] floatValue];
            CGContextSetLineWidth (gc, width);
            CGRect rect = [string1 frame];
            CGContextMoveToPoint(gc, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(gc, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
            CGContextStrokePath(gc);
        }
    }
```

this causes an error at `CGFloat width =[[string1.layer valueForKey:@"size234"] floatValue];`.
However, if i remove the release calls in the first method:

```
 [string release];
 [string1 release];
```

It runs fine.

Why is this causing an error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-ARC rule is to only release things that you've retained, explicitly or by calling such things as alloc or copy.  (More exact documentation is at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html )  `stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased object, which means you shouldn't be adding another release.

Comment: ok. thanks, but when i run my application while analyzing for allocations, since im creating 2 strings per time the touch moves, i get thousands of strings created. how would i release them/destroy them, because they are eating my memory.

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of using -stringWithFormat, i used [NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"asdf"]; thank you for the link

Comment: In response to your first comment, there is also the concept of "Autorelease Pool Blocks" which let you use the methods that return autoreleased objects while having more control over their life span.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this causing an error?

Because the method you called to create the strings, `-stringWithFormat:`, returns an auto released object. You didn't call alloc, retain, or copy, so you shouldn't call release.